# How do i search for an exact string in a cell in excel?

Tags: excel, find

I am trying to figure out how to search for exact string match in a cell in excel using vba.
For example I want to search for "the" in "There is the store" and have it only find "the" and not "There" since it also has the.
I am trying to do a auto search/replace and I keep on running to this issue where it replaces "The" part of there as well. I have looked into using Instr but that was no help. 
The data I am searching in is in cell A1 only.I looked into .find but seems like it only works with Column parameter. Am I missing something? Also, all my cell location is determined dynamically hence I cannot hard code the address.
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Show us what you've tried. A vague description really won't do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to do whole word replacement in Excel will ne using a **Regular Expression**

Here's a simple starting point.  Pass it a range, a Find Word, and a Replacement Word.  You ahould add error handling etc to suit your needs.

```vb
Sub ReplaceInRange( _
  r As Range, _
  FindWord As String, _
  Optional ReplaceWord As String = vbNullString)
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim mtchs As MatchCollection
    Dim mtch As Match

    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, col As Long

    ' Get Data from range
    If r.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim dat(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        dat(1, 1) = r.Value
    Else
        dat = r.Value
    End If


    ' Set up Regex
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.MultiLine = True
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "\b" & FindWord & "\b"

    'process the data
    For col = 1 To UBound(dat, 2)
    For rw = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
        If re.test(dat(rw, col)) Then
            dat(rw, col) = re.Replace(dat(rw, col), ReplaceWord)

            'Optional, remove double spaces
            dat(rw, col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(dat(rw, col))
        End If
    Next rw, col

    ' Return data to range
    r = dat
End Sub
```

Call is like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Get range to process by any means you choose
    Set rng = [A1:A2]

    ' Replace 'the' with blank
    ReplaceInRange rng, "the"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris!. That truly was helpful. However i ended up using the following..                   Instr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(i,j),"the ")>0                                    I just took advantage of the fact that there will be space after the. It is a quick fix but I am going to look at implementing RegExp as a more permanent solution.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Just remember, your search term may be followed by space _or_ punctuation, or may be the last few letters of a larger word.

Comment: Yeah that is why I am going to implement RegExp

Comment: Again thanks much for point me to the right direction